# is it a good practice to use app icon which is double the size of preferred size in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

i am working in an iPhone app, right now the standard size for appicon is `57x57`, but when i export the app icon in this size the app icon looks pixelated.

So i tried to use size `114x114`for appicon.png image and now the pixelation issue is fixed.

**is it a good practice to use app icon which is double the size of preferred size in iPhone?**

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apple's guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) show all the app icon sizes you should use

you should have a 114x114 for iPhone retina screens, and 144x144 for retina iPad. 57x57 is for non-retina iPhone/iPods